# Java K-means implementation with unexpected output

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm using the Trickl-Cluster project to cluster my data set 
and Colt to memorize the data objects in matrices .

After executing this code

```
import cern.colt.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D;
import cern.colt.matrix.impl.DenseDoubleMatrix2D;
import com.trickl.cluster.KMeans;

DoubleMatrix2D dm1 = new DenseDoubleMatrix2D(3, 3);
dm1.setQuick(0, 0, 5.9);
dm1.setQuick(0, 1, 1.6);
dm1.setQuick(0, 2, 18.0);
dm1.setQuick(1, 0, 2.0);
dm1.setQuick(1, 1, 3.5);
dm1.setQuick(1, 2, 20.3);
dm1.setQuick(2, 0, 11.5);
dm1.setQuick(2, 1, 100.5);
dm1.setQuick(2, 2,6.5);
System.out.println (dm1);

KMeans km = new KMeans();
km.cluster(dm1 ,1);
DoubleMatrix2D dm11 = km.getPartition();
System.out.println (dm11);
DoubleMatrix2D dm111 = km.getMeans();
System.out.println (dm111);
```

I had the following output

```
3 x 3 matrix
5.9   1.6 18  
2     3.5 20.3
11.5 100.5  6.5

3 x 1 matrix
1
1
1

3 x 1 matrix
6.466667
35.2     
14.933333
```

Following the algorithm steps , it's strange when one expects 1 cluster and has 3 means 
The documentation is not so clear about that specific point .

This is the definition of the method Cluster according to the java doc of the project

```
void cluster(cern.colt.matrix.DoubleMatrix2D data, int clusters)
```

So logically speaking the `int clusters` represents the number of the expected clusters after K-means terminates.

Have you any idea about the relation between the outputs of K-means class in the project and the K-means algorithm expected results?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but shouldn't you be using more than 1 as the input value to the cluster method? Otherwise wouldn't you just get a cluster that has the smallest distance to all the data points (i.e. the center)? Isn't the point of K-means to partition a data set between several cluster points?

Comment: Yes I've experienced 1 as input value on purpose .
Because with only one cluster , only one mean should be as an output whereas you see clearly that there are 3 means .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one *3-dimensional* mean. If you put in three-dimensional data, you get out three-dimensional means.

Note that running k-means with k=1 is absolutely nonsensical, as it will simply compute the mean of the data set:

```
(5.9+2+11.5) / 3 = 6.466667
(1.6+3.5+100.5) / 3 = 35.2
(18+20.3+6.5) / 3 = 14.933333
```

The result is obviously correct.

Comment: I know that 1 cluster makes no sense , In a previous comment I said that I did that on purpose .
You answer was very helpful . Thank You